# Io Language: Exception: Sequence does not respond to 'openForReading'

Tags: iolanguage

I'm study "seven languages in seven weeks".

On Io charpter, I run following example failed with following exception.

```
#phonebook.io
OperatorTable addAssignOperator(":", "atPutNumber")
curlyBrackets := method(
  r := Map clone
  call message arguments foreach(arg,
       r doMessage(arg)
       )
  r
)

Map atPutNumber := method(
  self atPut(
       call evalArgAt(0) asMutable removePrefix("\"") removeSuffix("\""),
       call evalArgAt(1))
)

s := File with("phonebook.txt" openForReading contents)

phoneNumbers := doString(s)
phoneNumbers keys println
phoneNumbers values println
```

## phonebook.txt

```
{
        "Bob  Smith" : "12345",
        "Mary Walsh" : "5678"
}
```

Exception message:

> Exception: Sequence does not respond to 'openForReading'   ---------
>   Sequence openForReading              phonebook.io 16   File with
>   phonebook.io 16   CLI doFile                           Z_CLI.io 140
>   CLI run                              IoState_runCLI() 1

phonebook.io and phonebook.txt in same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare code line by line, following line

```
s := File with("phonebook.txt" openForReading contents)
```

**should correct as:**

```
s := File with("phonebook.txt") openForReading contents
```

At last works as expected:

> $> io phonebook.io
>   list(Mary Walsh, Bob  Smith)
>   list(5678, 12345)